Arc length of a polar curve $r = -8\cos(t)$
If I am being asked to find the arc length of the polar curve
$r = -8\cos(t)$
when I use the integral formula it gives me $16 \pi$.
But since this polar curve represents a circle with radius 4, should not it be $2\pi r = 2\pi/4 = 8\pi$?
Maybe this is happening because my bounds are from $0$ to $2\pi$, if I consider it from $0$ to $\pi$ it would work perfectly, however I do not know why would I have to consider the bound only until $\pi$.
Any help would be appreciated!

Show that work that led to your $16\pi$ using the integral. Remember - the arc length measure in polar coordinates is different than the usual one!

So, first we need some parametric equations for the circle. Clearly, this is a circle with center $(-4,0)$ and radius $4$. Then the natural parameterization is given by
$$\left{ \begin{align*}
x(t) &= 4 \cos t - 4\
y(t) &= 4 \sin t \
t &\in [0,2\pi)
\end{align*} \right.$$
(You can see this parameterization in action here.) [cont.]

The arc length for a sufficiently-nice curve given in parametric form $(x(t),y(t))$ for $t \in [a,b]$ is given by
$$
\text{arc length} = \int_a^b \sqrt{ [x'(t)]^2 + [y'(t)]^2 } , \mathrm{d}t
$$
Using this method, I get $8\pi$ for the arc length. So it's hard to say where you went wrong with this method if you don't elaborate.

With a bit of thinking (and some picture drawing), there is a small subtlety.
While we expect one full rotation of the circle to fall in the parameter range $t \in [0, 2\pi),$ in this case, we need $t \in [0, \pi).$ Here's why.
Consider the graph of the function $y = -8\cos x$ in the usual rectangular coordinates. This has period $2\pi$ but it "collects" all possible values in its range in one half-period - that is, on $[0, \pi).$ As soon as we go past $x = \pi,$ we're "repeating" values in the range. In polar coordinates, we can think of this in the following way: when $t = 0,$ then certainly $r = -8.$ This means we plot $(-8, 0)$ in polar coordinates - the point that is coterminal with $(8, \pi).$ When $t = \frac{\pi}{2},$ we have $r = 0$, and this corresponds to the point $(0, \frac{\pi}{2}).$ Finally, with $t = \pi,$ we have $r = 8$, which brings us back to the first point. Using the parameter range $[0, 2\pi)$ has us tracing the circle twice, not once.
So, in the integral,
$$ L = \int_0 ^\pi \sqrt{r^2 + r_t ^2} \ dr = \int_0 ^\pi 8 \ dr = 8\pi$$ as we expect.

It is $\theta=0$ to $\pi$ because the circle $r=-8\cos\theta$ lies entirely in the left half-plane. Remember that $\theta$ measures the angle around the origin, not the circle's centre. In the polar coordinate system,
we adopt the convention that the radial coordinate $r$ can be negative by defining $(-r,\theta)\equiv(r,\pi+\theta)\equiv(r,\pi+\theta+2n\pi)$ for any angular coordinate $\theta$. Please learn about the polar coordinate system and its conventions. As you can see in the graph, $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $\pi$ in the circle $r=-8\cos\theta$ (green+black), and from $0$ to $2\pi$ in the circle $r=8$ (red). By the convention, coordinates of $A$ and $B$ are equivalent to those of $A'$ and $B'$ (diametrically opposite), respectively. Observe that $0\leq\theta\leq\frac\pi2$ in the lower half (black) and $\frac\pi2\leq\theta\leq\pi$ in the upper half (green). In contrast, $0\leq\theta\leq\pi$ (upper half) and $\pi\leq\theta\leq2\pi$ (lower half) in the case of the circle $r=8$ (red).

So, for the given circle $r=-8\cos\theta$, the arc length is given by
$$\Large \color{red}{\int_0^\pi\sqrt{r^2+\left(\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm d\theta}\right)^2}~\mathrm d\theta=8\pi\qquad\text{units}.}$$
which is the circumference of a circle with a diameter of $8$ units.
I hope this helps!
PS: You can also take $\theta=-\frac\pi2$ to $\frac\pi2$ by a convention. The difference between the upper and lower limit of $\theta$ is $\pi$ regardless of the convention.
